# Serving Static Files with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, static-files

I have a google app engine application and I'm trying to test the static_dir feature that is claimed in order to serve an html page that can import a javascript file.

My file structure is as follows:

```
/
  frontend/
    static/
      js/
        config.js
      html/
         test.html
    views/
      widget.html
```

and in my app.yaml, I have:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: frontend.static
```

test.html is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p> HELLO WORLD </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason I'm trying to get this text.html out of static_dir is to check how this serving functionality works so I can serve static files to the widget.html file under views.

I definitely don't understand how this serving thing works though, because nothing I thought would work works.

Through the browser I've tried hitting:

- localhost:8080/static/test
- localhost:8080/static/html/test
- localhost:8080/static/test.html
- localhost:8080/static/html/test.html

I've moved test.html into the static dir directly. Numerous other things, and in the logs I continually get 404 Not founds. The guides say:

"The handlers section defines two handlers for URLs. When App Engine receives a request for a URL beginning with /bootstrap, it maps the remainder of the path to files in the bootstrap directory, and if an appropriate file is found, the contents of the file are returned to the client"

Sounds like what I'm doing should be working, but I'm seeing nothing.

Additionally if I were to try to import a javascript file into an html document, using this static_dir thing would I just list the relative directory as the source i.e. src="/static/css/stuff.css"> or would I have to include the entire url? i.e. src="localhost:8080/static/css/stuff.css">.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: to start, you don't have a `frontend.static` dir in your app,  use `frontend/static` instead

Comment: also - in which dir is your app.yaml file located?